# Adding a reference to an assembly with a specific range of versions in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, gac

In Visual Studio, you can require that an assembly reference match a specific version of the assembly. Is it possible (maybe by directly editing the csproj or vbproj file in a text editor) to reference a range of versions.

My specific example is I want to reference version 2.5.x of [nUnit](http://nunit.com) in my test projects at work. People run different versions of nUnit, and anything in version 2.5.x of nUnit should suffice for running our unit tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your compile settings, I don't believe so.

You can however, configure your app to redirect assembly load requests.  Have a look at [Assembly Binding Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2(VS.80).aspx).  You can configure load requests for a specific versions (or range of versions) to be redirected to something different at runtime.

This example is slightly modified from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys(VS.80).aspx):

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="myAssembly"
                              publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
                              culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.99.99.99"
                             newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Set the name, publicKeyToken and newVersion attributes correctly, and you should be good to go.